# Excel: How can I pick one row of a table based on the max value in one of the columns, and then copy cells of that row?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this table regarding the scores in a game. **Score** and **Final Score** are calculated by some formulas.

[image: Table]

I would like that, in the Final Score of the Hi-Score, the max value of the column J appeared (in this case 318) and that all the informations regarding that Final Score went above in the corresponding cells.

How can I do this? What formulas do I need to insert in the O column? Thank you.

Comment: You can do a max on J and move that to the left of all your data to do a vlookup?

Comment: `INDEX(RAnge,MATCH(MAX(IF(Range = Value,Range),RAnge,0))`

Comment: Ugh. I will never learn index/match XD

Comment: @ScottCraner I don't understand

Comment: @findwindow - You should try! It's one of my most used formulas.  [This page](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/) does a pretty good job, see their last tip for a great summary, "=INDEX ( `Column I want a return value from` , MATCH ( `My Lookup Value` , `Column I want to Lookup against` , Enter “0” ))".  There's [this site](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions03.html) too.

Comment: I can't shake off my vlookup habit ;_;

Comment: @ScottCraner I don't understand why you didn't actually answer the question; either way thanks, I did it using that method

Comment: In O1 `=INDEX($A$2:$J$4,MATCH(MAX($D$2:$D$4),D$2:$D$4,0),MATCH(N1,$A$1,$J$1,0))` I only put this here because I was leading you down the wrong path earlier. Put in O1 and drag down.

Comment: @findwindow *shudder* :P

Comment: I am ok with being spoonfed by Batman.

Comment: @BruceWayne **excellent** link <3 But if I don't use it by tomorrow, it's going out the window XD

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Building on Scott Craner's answer from the comments in answer form since I can't comment.

```
=INDEX(RAnge,MATCH(MAX(Range),RAnge,0))
```

The first range in that formula is the range of the data you want to find. So if you want to find the hits, that range would be A2:A4. To find level, that range would be G2:G4

The second and third range will both be the final score column.

Here is the formula as it should be written to find the total hits for the highest final score in cell O1:

```
=Index(A2:A4,Match(Max(J2:J4)),J2:J4,0)
```

Comment: When using someone else's comment as an answer, its kind to give them a shout out, just FYI

Answer (score 2):

One formula in O1:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$J$4,MATCH(MAX($J$2:$J$4),J$2:$J$4,0),MATCH(N1,$A$1:$J$1,0))
```

And drag down.  IF column N is spelled exactly like the header row it will automatically grab the correct column.